# Tracking video plays

Tags: php, javascript, video, video-streaming

We have our own media player built in Javascript and I was wondering if you had any suggestions on best practices for tracking video plays.  Up until now, we had a PHP script proxy the download and increment a counter with each play but I am thinking there has to be a better way.

The more research I do, the more it seems like looking at log files is the most reliable way to do so but we won't always have access to log files.

Is a Javascript pingback my only alternative?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To appropriately monitor useful video playing metrics, you need to watch it client-side.  That way, you can track:

- Whether the video was actually played
- How long the video was played
- If the viewer skipped ahead
- If the sound was muted
- If the video player was even visible in the scroll pane
- etc.

Have some JavaScript fire off a small AJAX call, or similar, and send the data back to your analytics server that way.  You will get far more useful information with this method.